# Simple CSS issue, styling the button size

Tags: html, css

I have a button that has only one letter in it. this is the HTML for it:

```
<button type="button" class="clicker">X</button>
```

I need to resize that button to make it smaller as much as I need, and also to keep that letter following the size of the button.

I have tried the following css andit resizes the button, but the text is not following. It is either at the bottom of the button or not visible at all.

```
.clicker {
float: right;
font-family:"Calibri",Arial,Sans Serif;
font-size:1.0em;
line-height: 30px;
color:red;
text-align: center;
wordwrap: center;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;

width:  30.0px;
height: 25.0px;

}
```

Comment: Does the button modify in size? Also, have you considered using an image instead of text for your button?

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the `line-height` to `23px`

http://jsfiddle.net/GfETQ/1/

Comment: @qwerty that's what I did! give it a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `font-size` and `line-height` properties. Use `vertical-align` instead.

```
.clicker {
    font-family: "Calibri", Arial, Sans Serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color:red;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/7wCLu/

Answer (score 0):

It's just becuase of your `line-height`. Remove it and it works :)

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LBdQ3/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.clicker {
    float: right;
    font-family:"Calibri", Arial, Sans Serif;
    font-size:1.0em;
    color:red;
    text-align: center;
    wordwrap: center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    width: 30.0px;
    height: 25.0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change to `line-height: 20px;` then it will center.